# Running python file from php

Tags: php, python

Solved But

Now it's runing but say to me in php index this :

```
/sbin/ejabberdctl: line 279: /home/ejabberd/var/lock/ejabberdctl/ejabberdctl-99: Permission denied /sbin/ejabberdctl: line 279: /home/ejabberd/var/lock/ejabberdctl/ejabberdctl-100: Permission denied Ran out of connections to try. Your ejabberd processes may be stuck or this is a very busy server. For very busy servers, consider raising MAXCONNID in ejabberdctl None None
```

what should I do, thnx.

I'm trying to run Python file with php

in php file I put:

```
passthru('python /home/register/register.py '. $_POST['username'] . ' example.com ' . $_POST['password'] . ' ' . $_POST['email'] . ' ' . $ip . ' 1 2>&1');
```

it's return with this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/register/register.py", line 46, in iplog = Writer("ip.txt") File "/home/register/register.py", line 35, in __init__ self.file = open(self.filename, "a") IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ip.txt'
```

say Permission denied and the user of php is : apache

also I try : exec & shell_exec and the samething

and am try chmod 777 and samething

How can I fix it, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's opening the file in the correct directory? Try changing `ip.txt` to the full pathname of the file.

Comment: 777 means anyone can read and write. You'll want to either chmod 755 (everyone can read and execute), or alteratively 700, and chown apache. the files. If you're writing to other files in the directory and need to create new ones, you'll want to make sure the directory housing the files is also able to be written by the apache user.

Comment: As @Barmar Sait, are you sure the URL is correct? On my hosting it shows me that directory is /sub/subdomain/blabla but the real path is root of the server, which for me is /data/web/domain.xx/sub/subdomain/blabla Also I am using exec instead of passthru.

Comment: @Barmar yes, also I try what you say. not working

Comment: @PatrickWebster I try to chmod 755 and 700 samething

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB I change path and samething, Not Working

Comment: @PatrickWebster How can I set apache to can use : sudo or to set it like root

Comment: @deounix Do not use the same path as I have (also, sub is for subdomain, for main domain its just /data/web/domain.xx/www/blabla), cos your server might have different path. Are you the owner of the server? If not, check the FAQ of company you ahve server from, it might be there. If not, ask them for complete path, so you can use python.

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB I'm using VDS Centos OS - Yes I'm owner and am not use like ur path I mean I put full path like this : /home/register/ip.txt

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB it's say : IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/register/ip.txt

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB I think this problem from apache user but I don't know what should I do.

Comment: Hmmm. Did you try exec instead of passthru? Also, do all parent directories and file have execution rights? Not only file itself.

Comment: @MiChAeLoKGB yes I try exec & shell_exec. not working

Comment: Im gonna link you here: http://superuser.com/a/455994

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is in your python script.  I just ran the following:

```
//index.php
passthru('python /tmp/register.py  2>&1');

#/tmp/register.py
print 1
```

and the webpage shows "1".  Can you try running `python register.py` from the command line and letting us know what the error is?  Also, post the pertinent parts of the python file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the permission problem about ip.txt, your python script don't have the permission to access ip.txt.

Comment: chown nobody.nobody ip.txt & make sure chmod, have a try.